# Vue.js Call method from another component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-resource

I have 2 components. How can I call `fetchProjectList()` method in `createProject()` method.

**First component:**

```
Vue.component('projects', {
    template: '#projects-template',

    data: function () {
        return {
            list: []
        }
    },

    ready: function () {
        this.fetchProjectList();
    },

    methods: {
        fetchProjectList: function () {
            resource.get().then(function (projects) {
                this.list = projects.data;
            }.bind(this));
        }
    }

});
```

**Second component**

```
Vue.component('createProjects', {
    template: '#create-projects-template',

    methods: {
        createProject: function () {
            resource.save({}, {name: this.name}).then(function () {
                this.fetchProjectList()
            }.bind(this), function (response) {
                // error callback
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: How are these components linked? Do they have a common parent?

Comment: No they don't have a common parent. I'm beginner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't, or rather you shouldn't. components should not depend on other components in such a direct way.

You should either extract this method into a [mixin](http://vuejs.org/guide/mixins.html), or keep it in it's own object which you import into each component.

Read up on the store pattern: http://vuejs.org/guide/application.html#State_Management

Comment: Depending on their relationship, using events might be a good solution as well.